# Register class with multiple interfaces for Dependency injection in Catel

Tags: c#, mvvm, catel

I'm using Catel 5.12.19 with an MVVM application

I have the following 2 interfaces:

```
  public interface ICustomerSearch
{
    public List<string> CustomerSearchFilterList { get; set; }
    public int SelectedFilter { get; set; }               
    public List<ICustomer> OnFindCustomer();
}
```

and

```
  public interface IService
{
}
```

I implement them as follow:

```
 public class CustomerControlService: IService, ICustomerSearch
    {        
        public IDBContext dbContext;    
    public List<string> CustomerSearchFilterList { get { return GetAvailableFilters(); } set {}
    public int SelectedFilter { get; set; }


    public CustomerControlService()
    {
        dbContext = new Model();            
    }
    public CustomerControlService(IDBContext context)
    {
        dbContext = context;            
    }

    public List<ICustomer> OnFindCustomer()
    {
        return new List<ICustomer>(dbContext.Customers);
    }

    private static List<string> GetAvailableFilters()
    {
        List<string> Result = new()
        {
            "Option 1",
            "Option 2"
        };
        return Result;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In the app.xaml.cs I register this as follow:

```
ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterType<IService, CustomerControlService>();
```

In my model I inject it in the constructor like:

```
public CustomerControlViewModel(IService customerControl/* dependency injection here */) 
    {
        customersController = (CustomerControlService)ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IService>();                   
    }
```

But then I can't do:

```
 public List<string> CustomerSearchFilterList = customersController.CustomerSearchFilterList;
```

Can I accomplish this and how?

Jeroen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IService` interface is blank, therefore any code using `IService` can perform no actions with it.

`CustomerSearchFilterList` is defined as belonging to `ICustomerSearch` interface.

Thus for dependency injection you should be using concrete classes based upon `ICustomerSearch` instead of `IService`.

You can combine interfaces to form more complex ones e.g.

```
public interface IComplexInterface : ICustomerSearch, IService
{
}
```

Then you could inject concrete classes based upon `IComplexInterface` and call interface methods or properties from both `ICustomerSearch` and `IService`

Comment: This works. I missed the effect of the blank intercae